# How to Read 3 Million Records from RODBC and write to Text File

Tags: r, rodbc

I'm reading 3 Million Records from a table and i want to Write it to a text file, but i'm facing as the program is running out of Memory throwing an error

> Exceeded maximum space of Memory 3096 MB.

My System Configuration is i5 Processor with 4 GB RAM.

Please find below code.

```
library(RODBC)
con  <- odbcConnect("REGION", uid="", pwd="")

a <- sqlQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM dbo.GERMANY where CHARGE_START_DATE = '04/01/2017'");
write.table(a,"C:/Users/609354986/Desktop/R/Data/1Germany.txt",na="",sep="|",row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE)

close(con)
```

Comment: *Don't*? R isn't an ETL tool. Your database already has some very good tools for this. 3M rows is *small data* for a database. Which database are you using and *why* are you trying to expor the data in the first place?

Comment: Why not use the new version of dplyr and do what you need with the database out of memory? Then bring it into R when you have something (presumably smaller) that you want to analyse.

Comment: I'm Trying to Connect to SQL Server using an ODBC Connection. I Just want to retrive the data from the database and do the necessary transformations for my need. i was able to do this for Smaller Tables but for this particular table of 3 Million Records, i'm running out of memory, not sure how to handle it

Comment: R is not the right tool for this. It will be extremely slow compared to "native" database solution. You can even use a plain SQL client and redirect to file...

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is add an index to your db table so you can loop through it and extract/write your data piece by piece without filling up your memory
here is an example

```
   # create that index
    sqlQuery(channel, 'alter table dbo.GERMANY ADD MY_COL NUMBER')

    sqlQuery(channel, 'update dbo.GERMANY set MY_COL = rownum ')

    # the function
    g <- function(a) {

      for (i in (1:length(a))) {
      query <- gsub('\n',' ', paste( "SELECT * FROM dbo.GERMANY where 
                         CHARGE_START_DATE = '04/01/2017 and
                       my_col between",a[i] ," and ", a[i+1], collapse = ' '));

      df <- sqlQuery(channel, query) ; 

      write.csv(df, paste('my_',i,'_df.csv')) ;
      }
    }

    # use reasonable chunks 
    a <- seq(1,3000000,250000)


    g(a)
```

Comment: Hi Mouad, I have Read Only access to the table, hence cannot add a column, Due to Some data Security Policies in the company i have to access the Data using only ODBC Connection and that is where i'm facing the problem.

Comment: is there a column that can be reasonably used as an index? I know that `rownum` gets generated by the query in Oracle, so that won't work, but any sort of ranked column could work.